# Is there a Vega-lite equivalent to the scale_y_continuous function?

Tags: powerbi, visualization, vega-lite, deneb

I have a graph visualized in R that I'd like to create in PowerBI using Deneeb. In R there's the function "scale_y_log10". Is there a way do the same thing in Vega-lite?

I've used the basic "scale": "type:"log", but I'd like to do more.

Comment: What does "scale": "type:"log" not give you that you require?

Comment: I can't use "scale:"type:"log and set the domain view at the same time (to my knowledge)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure the values in your combined axis do not contain negative numbers on a log scale.

```
{
  "data": {"name": "dataset"},
  "transform": [
    {
      "filter": "datum['virus'] !== null"
    },
    {"filter": "datum['virus'] !== 0"}
  ],
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "date",
      "title": "Date",
      "type": "temporal"
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "virus",
      "title": "(Normalized Levels (N1/PMMOV Concentrations)",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "scale": {"type": "log"}
    }
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "point",
        "tooltip": true,
        "filled": true
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "line",
        "color": "black"
      },
      "transform": [
        {
          "filter": "datum['virus'] != null"
        },
        {
          "filter": "datum['virus'] != 0"
        },
        {
          "loess": "virus",
          "on": "date",
          "as": ["a", "b"],
          "bandwidth": 0.3
        },
        {"filter": "datum['b'] >1"}
      ],
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "a"},
        "y": {"field": "b"}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```